# Itext PDF files not being generated

Tags: java, itext

I have written a java application in windows using neat beans IDE. The application uses i-text to generate reports, While in the development environment, the reports are successfully generated. When I convert to windows executable file, the reports are generated successfully on my computer. However when i install the application on another computer, the reports are no longer generated successfully. Any help please?

Comment: Which version of iText?

Comment: the i text  version is 5.2.1